# How could I capture that the server side code is finished executing?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm calling a code on a form submit that shows a gif loading image to inform the user that the code is in progress.

```
<form runat="server" onsubmit="ShowLoading();">
</form> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowLoading(e) {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.setAttribute("id", "loadingMsg");
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = 'images/ld_gif2.gif';
        div.style.cssText = 'position: fixed; top: 30%; left: 40%; z-index: 5000; width: 222px; text-align: center; ';
        div.appendChild(img);
        var parnt = document.getElementById('prnt');
        parnt.appendChild(div);


    }



</script>
```

The image is shown onsubmit. But it doesn't disappear after submission ends. I need an event that fires when the submission is finished to hide the loading image.

Comment: Just to draw your attention, this will be complex code. I recommended to create a div with loader and just show/hide from submit click.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below function to remove loading image on finish

```
function HideProgressImage()
{
document.getElementById('loadingMsg').style.display="none";
}
```

Hope this will help..